# L'hospital rule for two variable, one undefined

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I kind of understand how to calculate L'hospital, but I need help for this one, I cannot convert this to $$\frac{0}{0}$$, because $$\frac{(10-a)x^3}{(10+a)x^3}$$, I can replace only x=∞. What is the correct way to calculate such math problem?

$lim_{x\to∞} $$\frac{(10-a)x^3 + 2x^2-(a+1)x-2a}{(10+a)x^3+21x+3a+2}$

Comment: Tip: L'Hopital's rule is not advised to be used here unless specified otherwise. Reason: It might get troublesome for beginners and time consuming as well. Just divide the top part and bottom part by $x^3$ and you are good to go! [Just a casual tip guys, no worries]

Answer (score 1):

As far as $x$ cares, $a$ is just a constant by any other name. So you should be able to apply L'Hopital's rule just fine, just treating $a$ as a constant, provided everything else remains well-defined as $x \to \infty$. If you prefer, you can think of taking the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ at each stage.

Hence, for example
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2 + ax+a }{x^2 - ax+a }
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2 + ax+a) }{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2 - ax+a) }\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x+a}{2x-a}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x+a)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x-a)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2 }{ 2}\\
&=1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: But if a = 10 then we have

$\frac{(10-10)^3}{(10+10)^3}$
and 

$\frac{0x^3}{20x^3}$

Doesn't that change the whole task

Comment: Why would it change anything? It would mean a limit of zero. Issues would only arise for the $a$'s which make the expression undefined, e.g. $a=-10$ since they would cause a division by zero -- but then you have issues much more important taking the limit in those scenarios anyways.

Comment: Yes, when I solved the problem (I hope it is correct) I got 

=$\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{10-a}{10+a}$

which will give same result as 

$\frac{(10-a)x^3}{(10+a)x^3}$

no matter what "a" is equal to, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if it is correct

$\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{\frac{∂}{∂x}(10-a)x^3+2x^2-(a+1)x-2a}{\frac{∂}{∂x}(10+a)x^3+21x+3a+2}$

= $\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{(10-a)3x^2+4x-a-1}{(10+a)3x^2+21}$

= $\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{\frac{∂}{∂x}(10-a)3x^2+4x-a-1}{\frac{∂}{∂x}(10+a)3x^2+21}$

= $\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{(10-a)6x+4}{(10+a)6x}$

= $\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{\frac{∂}{∂x}(10-a)6x+4}{\frac{∂}{∂x}(10+a)6x}$

= $\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{(10-a)6}{(10+a)6}$

= $\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{60-6a}{60+6a}$

= $\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{60-6a}{60+6a}$  /6

= $\lim_{x\to∞}$ $\frac{10-a}{10+a}$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).